# ERROR ITMS-9000 when uploading my Flash Pro CC Adobe AIR iPad app to iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, app-store-connect

I have developed an iPad app using Flash Pro CC.  My client has both an Apple iOS Dev license and an Apple iOS Enterprise Dev license.  I have successfully packaged and installed the app using the Enterprise license.  Now I am attempting to use their iOS Dev license to upload the app to the App store.  Every time, I get the same error.  Here's the summary at the bottom of the documentation:

```
1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/t1/f88tpcl88xl5f6008k8yjrkh0000gp/T/845653951.itmsp - Error Messages:
        Apple's web service operation was not successful
        Unable to authenticate the package: 845653951.itmsp
        ERROR ITMS-9000: "Unsupported Architectures. Your executable contains unsupported architectures '[cputype (12) cpusubtype (9)]'." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
        Could not start delivery: all transports failed diagnostics
```

I am not sure what "unsupported architectures '[cputype (12) cpusubtype (9)]'" means or how to fix it.  Could this have to do with third party libraries like Caurina Tweener or GreenSock?

I'm on a MacBook Pro 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7 running Mac OS X 10.9.2.  I'm attempting to upload using Application Loader Version 2.9.1 (441)

I have updated my OS to the latest version.  I have updated Application Loader to the latest version.  I have downloaded and installed the latest Apache Flex SDK (4.12.0) and linked it in my Flash Pro CC Compiler preferences.  I have downloaded and installed AIR 4.0.0.1628 and AIR Beta 13.0.0.64 and compiled an .ipa using each version of AIR and each one gave me the same error.

I'm reaching the end of my rope here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, because my last upload of an IOS app had been in January 2014. But I think this might have something to do with an email I have received from Apple.

Here is the relevant part of the message:
"Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK."

I don't know, if I have understood this right. But I would say, they don't accept apps built with Flash any more. I hope I'm wrong, because it would be time-consuming to learn to handle new tools.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My understanding is that the latest AIR update(s) bring the AIR Packager for iOS into compliance with the error message you mentioned. Upgrading Application Loader to the latest version is also required. I've seen others post that these updates have solved their errors.  Sadly, they haven't solved mine as of yet.

Comment: This is great, because it means, that Flash is still an option for developing IOS apps. So completely updated FlashCC and IOS developing tools should do it. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the thing uploaded.

The problem, it seems, is that I had not updated Xcode to the latest version.  I'd updated Application Loader and my AIR SDK, but it seems that some of Xcode's resources must be used in the packaging of the ipa file by Flash CC's iOS packager.  Updating Xcode rendered an ipa file that Application Loader was successfully able to upload.